# Inertia and Conservation of Angular Momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws

Suppose a 0.250 kg ball is thrown at 13.0 m/s to a motionless person standing on ice who catches it with an outstretched arm. 
What is his angular velocity if each arm has a 5.00 kg mass? You may treat his arms as uniform rods of length 0.9 m and the rest of his body as a uniform cylinder of radius 0.150 m. Neglect the effect of the ball on his rotational inertia and on his center of mass, so that it remains in his geometrical center.

I know that the $L=I \omega = mrv $

$ I = (m+\frac{M}{3})r^2 +\frac{1}{2}M_{b}r_{b}^2=(0.25+\frac{10}{3})0.9^2+\frac{1}{2}58*0.15^2=3.555$

$ mrv=0.25*13*0.9$

$ \omega = \frac{mrv}{I}=\frac{2.925}{3.555}=0.822$

This answer is incorrect. Please help me find where I made a mistake.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE. Please note that [homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [check-my-work questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) are largely off-topic here.

Comment: What is the moment of inertia of the person's body?  You are implying that it is zero.

Comment: Wouldnt the moment of inertia of the body be $ I = \frac{1}{2} M_b r_b^2=\frac{1}{2}*0.15^2 $?

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understand correctly, they don't want you to include the moment of inertia of the ball in the moment of inertia of the person. 2. The arms are 0.15 m away from the center. 3. The mass of the body is missing in the formulation of the problem.